# Fragment Output Interface incorrect?

Tags: fragment, shader, pipeline, vulkan

I'm new to vulkan and setting up a graphics pipeline right now. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYKlEIzGmW4&list=PL8327DO66nu9qYVKLDmdLW_84-yE4auCR&index=4&ab_channel=BrendanGalea) tutorial series.

So [VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-alphaToCoverageEnable-08891](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-alphaToCoverageEnable-08891) is the error I'm getting and I don't quite understand it. So what I understand is that since I defined for a Fragment Shader Stage to exist in the pipeline it's output interface must be a vec4 i.e. have an alpha  channel (like rgba).

This is my fragment shader (im using glslc to compile it):

```
#version 450


layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
void main() {
    outColor = vec4(0.75, 0.65, 0.8, 1.0);
}
```

The Code to create the renderpass:

```cpp
void SwapChain::createRenderPass()
  {
    VkAttachmentDescription depthAttachment{};
    depthAttachment.format = findDepthFormat();
    depthAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    depthAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    depthAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depthAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depthAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    depthAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    depthAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkAttachmentReference depthAttachmentRef{};
    depthAttachmentRef.attachment = 1;
    depthAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachment = {};
    colorAttachment.format = getSwapChainImageFormat();
    colorAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    colorAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    colorAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    colorAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    colorAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

    VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef = {};
    colorAttachmentRef.attachment = 0;
    colorAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
    subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;
    subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentRef;

    VkSubpassDependency dependency = {};
    dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
    dependency.srcStageMask =
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
    dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
    dependency.dstStageMask =
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT;
    dependency.dstAccessMask =
        VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT | VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;

    std::array<VkAttachmentDescription, 2> attachments = {colorAttachment, depthAttachment};
    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo = {};
    renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attachments.size());
    renderPassInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
    renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
    renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pDependencies = &dependency;

    if (vkCreateRenderPass(device.device(), &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &renderPass) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
      throw std::runtime_error("failed to create render pass!");
    }
  }
```

[the visualization of the pipeline from the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OVlw.png)

I tried including everything that is necessary (really don't have much clue) let me know if you need more info or if your dedicated enough i can also upload all my code to github. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you intend to actually use the Alpha2Coverage feature? Looks like you have only one sample.

Comment: I get this feature allows for an alpha channel for the colors, right? Then I want to use it. Not sure what you mean by only one sample. If it's the shader then that is only for testing I think.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_to_coverage